# Adding mqtt_cpp lib to cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been trying to add the following module [mqtt_cpp](https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp) to my project, but as always with cmake I struggle. This time I've tried lots of things suggested on similar problems here on stackoverflow but without success. I keep getting the same errors. Something seems to work as the mqtt_cpp lib searches my machine for the required boost version which I first had to install. What I have tried so far is adding some of the following lines (not all at once of course) to the CMakeLists.txt files on root level or the one in my lib folder where I have this library as a git submodule under ***./lib/mqtt_cpp***.

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mqtt_cpp)

add_library(mqtt_cpp_iface SHARED IMPORTED) # or STATIC instead of SHARED

set_target_properties(mqtt_cpp_iface PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mqtt_cpp/include"
) 

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/mqtt_cpp/include)

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mqtt_cpp)
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findmqtt_cpp_iface.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "mqtt_cpp_iface", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mqtt_cpp_iface"
  with any of the following names:

    mqtt_cpp_ifaceConfig.cmake
    mqtt_cpp_iface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "mqtt_cpp_iface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "mqtt_cpp_iface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "mqtt_cpp_iface" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

In the mqtt_cpp readme it is advised to have your CMakeLists.txt something like this which I have tried to replicate

```
set(LIBNAME "your_project_name")
add_library(${LIBNAME} <your dependencies here>)

find_package(mqtt_cpp_iface REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${LIBNAME} LINK_PUBLIC mqtt_cpp_iface::mqtt_cpp_iface)
```

### My CMakeLists.txt files

./CMakeLists.txt:

```
# See https://cmake.org/examples/
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

project(neodisplay)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(src)

add_executable(NeoDisplay main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(NeoDisplay LINK_PUBLIC src)
target_link_libraries(NeoDisplay PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
target_link_libraries(NeoDisplay LINK_PUBLIC mqtt_cpp_iface::mqtt_cpp_iface)

find_package(rxcpp CONFIG)
find_package(mqtt_cpp_iface REQUIRED)
```

./lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(ws2812-rpi)
add_subdirectory(mqtt_cpp)
```

Comment: Using `find_package` implies that you have corresponded package already **installed**. Have you installed the project from the reference you show (https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp)? How have you installed it?

Comment: This is a header only library. Reading through their readme there is no mention of installing it. It is mentioned to add the ***mqtt_cpp/include*** folder to your include path before giving an example of how to build your project with g++ (
***g++ -std=c++14 -Ipath_to_mqtt_cpp/include your_program.cpp -pthread additional_options***)
I assumed this is what I needed to do (adding the include path) in my cmakelists.txt and that this was equivalent to "installing" this header only lib. The file mentioned in my error message ***mqtt_cpp_iface.cmake*** does not exist in the project directory

Comment: The file `mqtt_cpp_ifaceConfig.cmake` is created only on **installing** the project. Actually, you could avoid `find_package(mqtt_cpp_iface REQUIRED)` by using INTERFACE library target. This is similar to your first snippet, but with INTERFACE instead of IMPORTED: `add_library(mqtt_cpp_iface INTERFACE)`.

Comment: I changed the line ***target_link_libraries(NeoDisplay LINK_PUBLIC mqtt_cpp_iface::mqtt_cpp_iface)*** for ***target_link_libraries(NeoDisplay LINK_PUBLIC mqtt_cpp_iface)*** without the extra colons. As I've now read they stand for external libraries. **It seems** to build now as g++ output is listing files from the library. Unfortunatelly the raspberry pi which I'm running the project on is running out of memory and the build is ongoing now for hours. This is another problem completely of course. I guess I'll have to look into cross compiling or finding another library to use for my project.